# How to collapse a node if a node gets open in extjs treepanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

im using extjs treepanel.In that im dynamically loading parent and child node. I want to open one node at a time.i dont want two nodes to be opened at a same time . Is the are any event or property available in ext js ? Collapseall() method doesnt help me.

```
    var panel = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
        cls: 'shaperepository',
        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
        root: this.shapeList,
        autoScroll: true,
        rootVisible: false,
        lines: false,
        anchors: '0, -30',

    .....
          var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
                        cls: "Schematree",
                        loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
                        width: 150,
                        height: 250,
                        root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
                            expanded: true,
                            leaf: false,
                            text: 'Schema',
                            children: children
                        })
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `expand` event.

I don't know what exact behaviour you want from the question, but you could get the root node, run collapseAll with true for recursive to close all nodes. Then in the collaspeAll callback expand the node that the event was fired from and any of it's parents (recurse).

The documentation for [NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) could be of help.

The only other option that I can think of is to call collaspeAll on all siblings (previousSibling and nextSibling recursively) as well as the parent's siblings recursively. This would collapse all nodes except the node and it's parents that was just expanded. This method should result in less redraws, but I haven't tried either method.